# What does the POS field in a Pytorch Geometric Dataset Do?

Tags: mnist, pytorch-geometric, gnn

I'm looking at MNISTSuperpixels dataset, and I see a bunch of fields in each instance. X, Y, and edge_index I understand, but I can't for the life of me figure out what the POS field does.

Answer (score 1):

The POS fields contain information on the position of the objects represented by the nodes in whatever domain they belong. It does not provide information about the graph itself but rather the context in which the data is.

For example, in [this tutorial on the PyTorch docs](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started/introduction.html#data-transforms), the POS field contains the information of the points in their 3D shape point cloud.